# Using ProcessBuilder to execute commands that require comand line input

Tags: java

I was knocking up a app to try and help with my build process and was trying in include a `git pull origin` command. I've tried and tested all kinds of methods, but can't seem to get any input or output to work with that command.

The program waits on `Process.waitFor()` with no input or output.

I'm assuming the `git pull` command is waiting for me to input a username and password, but so far I've failed to establish how to achieve that.

There are numerous questions on SO coverings these kinds of examples, but none of the answers appear to be working for my use case.

The simplest code that I believe should work is:

```
class CmdTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "git pull origin");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Replacing the `git pull origin` with a `dir` will provide output as expected.

Comment: If you try any other git command as `git status` do you get any output. It's to know if the git command is correctly added to the console.

Comment: @SergioLema Yes, `git status` returns output as expected.

Comment: So, I think the problem remains in the credentials. Try to configure git to use your account (user.name and user.email into `.gitconfig`)

Comment: @SergioLema I've done that - if I do that it works fine. I'm just trying (and failing) to understand why the above isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Doing just `git pull origin` without the credentials configured by default, `git` will wait for them at any important action. In your code, you don't provide (neither look) for `git` feedback, so the application get stuck at this stage.

Configuring the default credentials for `git` into your `.gitconfig` file, any `git` command will use them and the console won't be stuck (neither your application).

Comment: This is a workaround rather than a solution. The `redirectXxx` calls should redirect all input, output and errors to the terminal and works correctly for processes that don't require input.